# Webstats for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-statistics

Is there a free thrid-party library/plugin that does webstats (web statistics i.e. number of page hits, logged in users, connection origin, etc.) that can integrate well with an ASP.NET MVC based website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest **[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/)**.

A simple script tag in your master page / layout is all you need to get an incredibly details statistics and analysis. And it's free.

Comment: Google Analytics is probably the best, and those types of plugins are platform agnostic, can be used in any type of web application, ruby, php, asp.net, whatever

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't need to be MVC based. You can use Log4Net and store audit in the database and then do your stats or just use Google Analytics adding the javascript for it